# Random shuffling of elements in an array between 2 indexes VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, random, arraylist, shuffle

I'm trying to shuffle elements between a certain number of indexes.

```
Dim rng As New Random()
For placeHolder As Integer = min To max Step -1
            Dim swapIndex As Integer = rng.Next(min, max)
            Dim temp As Object = myList(placeHolder)
            myList(placeHolder) = myList(swapIndex)
            myList(swapIndex) = temp
Next
```

Where 'min' is the value of the lowest index and 'max' is the value of the highest index. However each time I have tried it doesn't seem to be shuffling randomly (it always comes out alphabetically instead).

Comment: Just to clarify I'm using an ArrayList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `min` is the lowest and `max` is the highest, then your loop should not have `Step -1` in it. That will cause the loop to never execute.

Comment: Both really good answers - for my code Ross' solution worked better. As soon as the Step -1 was removed it started executing

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim rng As New Random()
For placeHolder as Integer = min To max-1 Step 1
   Dim swapIndex as Integer = rng.Next(placeHolder +1, max)
   Dim temp as Object = myList(placeHolder)
   myList(placeHolder) = myList(swapIndex)
   myList(swapIndex) = temp
Next
```

The changes?
I changed the max value being stepped over to 1 less than the end so that you don't waste time trying to swap the end with itself. I also changed the Step to +1 because min < max from your description. I changed the minimum random value to placeholder + 1 because I don't want to re-swap what I've already swapped. This last change is optional though.